# Is there a Java equivalent for Python's map function?

Tags: java, python, collections

I would like to easily transform a collection (list) of objects of class A to a collection of objects of class B, just as Python's map function does it. Is there any "well-known" implementation of this (some kind of library)? I've already searched for it in Apache's commons-lang but with no luck.

Comment: In Python `map()` would properly not be the preferred way to do this, instead most would use a generator expression or list comprehension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

still not exist

**functional programming** features will be added in [Java 8 - Project Lambda](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/)

I think [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is best for your needs now

Comment: Yup, Collections2.transform appears to do what I need.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from **Java 8**, it can be done thanks to the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) using an appopriate **mapper** [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that we will use to convert our instances of class `A` to instances of class `B`.

**The pseudo code would be:**

```
List<A> input = // a given list of instances of class A
Function<A, B> function = // a given function that converts an instance 
                          // of A to an instance of B
// Call the mapper function for each element of the list input
// and collect the final result as a list
List<B> output = input.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is a concrete example that will convert a `List` of `String` to a `List` of `Integer` using [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) as mapper function:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> output = input.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(output);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

For **previous versions** of `Java`, you can still use [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) from **Google Guava** to replace the `Stream` and use [`com.google.common.base.Function`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html) instead of `java.util.function.Function` as **mapper function**.

**The previous example would then be rewritten as next:**

```
List<Integer> output = FluentIterable.from(input)
    .transform(
        new Function<String, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(final String value) {
                return Integer.valueOf(value);
            }
        }
    ).toList();
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several functional libraries mentioned [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1223), most of which probably cover map:

> http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~bringert/hoj/
>   programmer (includes Java 5.0 generics
>   support). Little documentation.
>
> http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/sandbox/functor/
>   doesn't look like it is maintained,
>   doesn't support generics. Little
>   documentation.
>
> http://devnet.developerpipeline.com/documents/s=9851/q=1/ddj0511i/0511i.html
>   library.
>
> http://functionalj.sourceforge.net
>
> http://www.functologic.com/orbital/
>
> http://jga.sourceforge.net/
>   programming in java (includes
>   generics). Looking forward to more
>   documentation, perhaps better
>   organization of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Could take a look at Google's Guava library:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try guava, but you are likely to find that if you use an anonymous class its will be more complicated and longer than just using a loop.

```
List<OldType> list1 =
List<NewType> list2 = new ArrayList<NewType>(list1.size());
for(OldType element: list1);
   list2.add(transform(element));
```

Its worth remembering that Java is not a functional language and its often better to just use a loop. Perhaps when Java has closures .... sigh.

Comment: Good point, but it is sometimes more readible to define these kinds of operations in one instruction. Even if definition of anonymous class is longer. Besides, I was curious ;)

Comment: I would say its much clearer if you are used to reading the code that way. Unfortunately Java doesn't help much. :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj) and its [convert method](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/lambdaj/Lambda.java?r=1452#896)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, the Java equivalent for Python's map is called ... map !

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class ListMapExample
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List<int[]> arrays = integers.stream().map(size -> new int[size])
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        arrays.forEach(ary -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary)));
    }

}
```

This examples converts a list of integers to a list of arrays with the corresponding size :

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can also write more than one statement inside map :

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
Stream<int[]> arraysStream = strings.stream().map(string -> {
    int size = Integer.valueOf(string);
    int size2 = size * 2;
    return new int[size2];
});
arraysStream.map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

```
public abstract class MapF<T,S>
    {
        public abstract T f(S s) throws Exception;

        public List<T> map(List<S> input) throws Exception
        {
            LinkedList<T> output = new LinkedList<T>();
            for (S s: input)
                output.add(f(s));
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Simply, extends this class defining your function f and call the method map on the list.